# returning empty set when group by is using (ORACLE SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a script that takes as input three parameters from a user
and I would like to check if parameters are given and if table_name exists in database.
The problem I have is that because I am using group by function if 
there is no columns of given table result is empty

My code is

```
    SELECT COUNT(1),
  Case 
     WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN
        NVL2(:a,
        NVL2(:b, 
        NVL2(:name,
        TO_CLOB('code1')
        ,'Error : name is required')
        ,'Error : b is required')
        ,'Error : a is required')
    ELSE 
      TO_CLOB('Error : table name does not exist')
END
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME=UPPER(:name)
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Could you help me please ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is no need to use group by clause. because in the view USER_TAB_COLUMNS only 1 table can exiust with unique name. so it will always return blank result.

Comment: Use `exception` handling in the code.  Don't try to check every column and table being referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to create a dummy table that contains one row that outputs the parameter passed in, and then left join the above query to that. E.g.:

```
select count(utc.table_name),
       case when count(utc.table_name) > 0 then
            nvl2(:a, nvl2(:b, nvl2(:name, to_clob('code1'),
                                          'Error : name is required'),
                              'Error : b is required'),
                     'Error : a is required')
            else to_clob('Error : table name does not exist')
       end
from   (select upper(:name) table_name from dual) d
       left outer join user_tab_columns utc on (d.table_name = utc.table_name)
group by d.table_name;
```